# Adding CSS to new document created by Javascript

Tags: javascript, css

I'm trying to create a blank document with Javascript, and then import the CSS file I already have with it.

Here is my code:

```js
function printData() {
  let ptimetable = document.getElementById("timetable");
  let printWin = window.open("");
  printWin.document.write(ptimetable.outerHTML);
  let hd = printWin.document.getElementByTagName("head")[0];
  let link = printWin.document.createElement("link")
  link.rel = "stylesheet";
  link.type = "text/css";
  link.href = "../css/main.css";
  hd.appendChild(link);
  

  //printWin.print();
  //printWin.close();

}
```

I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong - the document is created, but the CSS from my file doesn't apply to the table.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Thanks!

- R

Comment: Open the network tab of your browser's developer tools. Look at the request for the stylesheet. Is the URL what you expect?

Comment: Using the Network tab of the Developer Tools in your browser of choice, is the CSS file found and downloaded?

Comment: I think that's the problem. Cheers for the help.

Answer (score 0):

After the comments I've seen, the problem resides in the incorrect CSS link. There's also an issue with one of the functions that I have seemingly just made up in my head. Thanks everyone